# Game loop design

Tags: c++, windows

I'd like to create a simple game loop. I'm taking into account this 2 versions:

v.1:

```
while (continueRunning) {

        PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        if (WM_QUIT == msg.message) {
            continueRunning = false;
        }

        // run the game logic

    }
```

and
v.2:

```
while(continueRunning)
{
    // peek for messages
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            continueRunning = false;
    }

    // run the game logic
}
```

What's better solution? Is it necessary to have the `PeekMessage` in the `while` loop like in the second example?

Comment: Are you missing a `break;` in the 2nd example?

Comment: No, there is no need for it in the inner loop since when the `PeekMessage` gets `WM_QUIT` message it sets `continueRunning = false` and when there are no any messages left in the queue the `PeekMessage` returns `0` causing the inner loop breaks and then since now `continueRunning = false` also outer loop breaks.

Comment: But you'll immediately call `PeekMessage()` again, even if `continueRunning` is `false`. Also I don't see that your game logic is reached at all. Did you even try running this?

Comment: One of the better ways to see if your intended flow makes sense its to draw it. Make a little flow chart. If the flow chart can't show what you need to show, you're heading down a bad path. If you can't draw the flow chart clearly because it's got lines going all over the place, you're probably headed in a bad direction. If you have a good diagramming tool, you can do a lot of very effective debugging very easily at the flow chart level long before writing a single line of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first version is missing an `if` around `PeekMessage`. Anyway, it will process **ONE** message in a game cycle (~60 per second?). That's way too slow.

You should process all messages before running your game logic, similar to your `v.2`.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the second one is better as it will not run the TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage methods when PeekMessage returns false (or anything which converts to false). The main fallback though is that if it returns true it will run the whole loop again. This may or may not be the functionality you intend. Without knowing exactly what PeekMessage is meant to do it's difficult to provide any more insight.